# Count Number of elements with C# Watin

Tags: c#

So I need to count the number of element occurence in the browser using C# Watin, problem is it's not recounting once I load another pagination and my do while loop is skipping my while trap. the browser works like scrolling pagination where first 50 data where loaded then it needs to scroll to load another 100 so if that's the sequence it must be like

testing = 50 then page scroll then testing must be 100 then I need to check if testing hits my counter and that testing variable must be greater than or equal to counter to proceed. example

counter = 250
testing = 50

testing >= counter

somehow I need to recount the number of element occurrence when the page scrolls, but it's not working it always give me 50 even I scroll it

```
getJobCount = browser.Span(Find.ById(txtJobCountID)).ToString();
do
{                    
    do
    {
        testing = 0;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        browser.WaitForComplete(40);
        SendKeys.Send("{END}");
        testing = browser.Divs.Filter(Find.ByClass("gwt-Label WOTL")).Count;

        //MessageBox.Show("Test with Scroll = " + testing.ToString());

    }
    while (testing >= counter)

    counter++;

} 
while (counter != Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text));
```

Comment: what is `counter`? why do you do `testing = testing + testing`? Aren't you supposed to retrieve the elements by `browser.Spans.Filter(Find.By...` ? `testing` keeps growing, but counter stays static, your `while` condition may either run once or infinite loop (or until overflow).

Comment: please post the outer loop with it's condition. I see `testing` being initialized on top at a `"Test without Scroll"`, but this value is used in the loops. and is doubled each iteration until it hits the counter. How do you intend to use it in the scrolling case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your while condition is the wrong way. Assuming that `testing` is growing with each iteration you need to check whether it is still smaller than then limit `counter`

```
while (testing <= counter)
```

reading: do while `testing` still smaller than `counter`

your condition (up to now) is false unless at the first iteration the `testing` gets a value above 251

Comment: yes counter is the limit of scrolling, so i should put like testing = 0 at the start of do? before Thread.Sleep(1000);? but why is the while skipping my condition while (testing >= counter);?

Comment: @GoryTinio before the loop actually, what does the outer loop do?

Comment: the other loop was just like this
textbox1.text= number of items total
do
{
  // do something here
} while (counter != Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text));

Comment: Thanks yes I notice I got confused with greater than and less than conditions